# SUM function in SPARQL

Tags: sql, rdf, sparql, ontology, sparqlwrapper

This SUM aggregate function is not working. It gives no result.

```
select  (SUM(?p) as ?prcc) ?sune

where { 

?inl Sp:hasp ?p.

     ?inl Sp:hassuid ?supid.

?supid Sp:hassune ?sune.

}
GROUP BY ?sune
```

The data in "p" is in double format. So when i change my query to

```
select  (SUM(xsd:double(?p)) as ?prcc) ?sune

or select  (SUM(xsd:integer(?p)) as ?prcc) ?sune
```

It does not perform SUM on values with decimal point.

Comment: Please show some sample triples

Comment: **`The data in "p" is in double format.** Do you mean the literals are actually datatyped literals with the datatype xsd:double, or that they're strings whose characters are suitable lexical forms for an xsd:double?  As @TomaszPluskiewicz says, you need to show some data, or else we can't really help.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  (SUM(?p))
WHERE
{
  VALUES (?p) {
         (10.5) 
         (20.5)
  }
}
```

I tried this on online editor [SPARQL online editor](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) it works fine..may be u can try it on your sample data.